# join six tables with date ans market column repeating in all the tables.

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I have six tables in my database with 45 columns each,with date ans market column repeating in all the tables. 1 million records in it. my date and market values are not unique and is repeating so how can i join these tables together ? 
any help ?
For eg:

```
table 1:
date market col1 col2
1 may India  san  det
1 may USA    lif   det
2 may India  lif   san 

table 2 : 
date market col3 col4
1 may  india san  go
1 may  USA   dif  dic
2 may  ind   det   san


RESULT AS 
date market col1 col2 col3 col4 
1 may India  san det  san  go
1 may USA    lif det  dif   dic
2 may India  lif san  det   san
```

I tried joining two tables using the query like :

select * from cre,dur where cre.period = dur.period and cre.market = dur.market;

But once i try creating a table its not working .

I joined six tables by hard coding all the column names but is not the right way i think ?
Any HELP ?

Comment: Not sure what your problem is with hard coding the column names. You would need to specify which columns to join the tables on. Am I approaching your problem correctly, or am I way off the mark?

Comment: i have around 140 columns coming up when i add six tables, So is there any way joining these tables without writing all 140 column names ?

Comment: But surely you arent joining on 145 columns?

Comment: i have two columns  date and market same in all the six tables

Answer (score 0):

You can use in below way-

```
select cre.*,dur.* from cre,dur where cre.period = dur.period and cre.market = dur.market;
```

Note: Even your requirement is not much clear to me but as per my understanding you skip cre.period=dur.period then also you can get same results as per your data.

Even better to keep only required column, for this you can follow below steps-

Step1: Export below query results.

```
select * from table1 limit1;
```

Step2: Copy all columns from header line and remove unwanted columns.

Further your table structure does not seems good, you should keep one table's reference in another table through parent and child id.

Comment: this query works but when i put this query in a create table satement it gives an error ? i need all the columns .

Comment: i want to join these tables and pull out the data from mysql

Comment: If you are exporting this to mysql and then executing these exported statement as insert, If this is the case then actually your insert statement will be prepared as table name aliases instead of original table name in this case either you need to change table name in your insert statements before executing them or need to prepare query in different way...if this is the case then share your exported data sample and in which table you want to insert then i can help you.

Comment: I couldnt understand what you are mentioning